# UITextView *font* property is an optional in iOS 9. Is it nil by default?

Tags: ios, swift

Apparently iOS 9 changed the `UITextView.font` property to be a Swift optional type.  Does that imply the font property could be be nil on a new UITextView object (meaning it has to be tested for nil)?

If the font property on a newly construct UITextView object *is* nil, does that imply that UITextView will use default system font, or choose a user designated default font somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self explanatory:

```
import UIKit

let textView = UITextView()
let font  = textView.font
// let fontUnwrapped = textView.font! // crashes
textView.text = "hello"
let fontUnwrapped = textView.font! // <UICTFont: 0x7fbb8c917180> font-family: "Helvetica"; ...
```

Comment: So the font field is lazy-loaded. Probably a start-up speed optimization. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `font` property can be `nil`.  I just tried this in a Playground in Xcode 7.0.1 (Swift 2.0):

```
let view = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
print(view.font)  // "nil\n"
if (view.font == nil) {
    print("it is nil")  // "it is nil\n"
}
```

But, surprisingly it doesn't crash when you force unwrap it! (**Edit**: Read on, this isn't actually the case).

```
let font = view.font!
print(font.description)
```

Output:

> font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight:
>   normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt

The same behavior was observed in the iOS 9 Simulator.

---

[image: Playground showing above experiment]

**Update**

From @MartinR's observation in the comments, I was assigning to `view.text` before unwrapping the `view.font` which caused it to be assigned the default font value.

So, the answer to the original question is **yes, it can be `nil` and shouldn't be force unwrapped without testing**.

Comment: Forced unwrapping is never safe! You should unwrap `view.font` with `if let` statement.

Comment: you contradict yourself.. it can be nil but say force unwrapping is ok?

Comment: @mixel's absolutely right. Forced unwrapping uses a `!` for a reason--it's a warning that it should be used very, very sparingly.

Comment: That is *really* interesting and worth trying to understand. I'm sorry you got dinged so heavily for a noble attempt at an answer. Already I'm learning things from your research, and you certainly were not preaching to do the wrong thing. Hopefully people will undo their down votes in retrospect and simply discuss the tradeoffs in comments.

Comment: Is that some artifact of Swift's property observer pattern?

Comment: In your Playground screenshot, you *assign a value* to `view.text` (which seems to assign a default font as well). Without that, `let font = view.font!` crashes with "Unexpectedly found nil". (Tested on Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001), both Playground and compiled project.)

Comment: I just posted another question referring to your answer, to find out why you succeed in unwrapping an ostensibly nil pointer to find an initialized UITextView object. Really appreciate it. If I wasn't so desperately swamped for a work deadline I'd take some time to dig.

Comment: @MartinR, that is it.  Assigning a string to `view.text` then assigns the font!