# How is it possible to de-ref nil pointer in Swift/iOS 9 and retrieve an object?

Tags: ios, swift

I asked a question and someone answered with the following showing very strange/unexpected Swift behavior.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33201738/2079103

In that answer, the author shows code that *compares* a property of UITextView to nil and the test says reports it is nil. The code prints the value of the property, and it outputs  "nil".  But when he *assigns* the property to a variable, using `!` and prints the the variable, it shows a functional font object.

How is that possible?

I assume UITextView has some kind of property observer, but what in Swift accounts for that behavior?

Comment: It is not possible. Have a look at the latest comments to the referenced answer.

Comment: Alas, pilot error.  I'll never forget that assigning the `text` property also sets the `font` if it is `nil`.